# Issue with updating dynamic component loader

Tags: angular

In my ModalComponent, I have the following:

```
_eventEmitterService.modal.subscribe(stream=>{
    var component = ModalTemplateComponent;
    stream.subscribe(msg=>{
        this.componentRef.dispose();
        this.componentRef = null;
    });
    this._dcl.loadIntoLocation(component,_elementRef, 'modal').then((componentRef)=>{
       this.componentRef = componentRef;
    });
})
```

which worked very well, until I've updated to Angular 17.

In the changelog, I've read that:

> DynamicComponentLoader.loadIntoLocation has been removed. Use
>   @ViewChild(‘myVar’, read: ViewContainerRef) to get hold of a
>   ViewContainerRef at an element with variable myVar. Then call
>   DynamicComponentLoader.loadNextToLocation

So, as I understand, I need to add:

```
@ViewChild('selector-modal') child:ModalComponent;
```

to component that hold the ModalComponent.

However, I am not quite sure how I should then load my new component in the `ModalComponent`:

```
 this._dcl.loadIntoLocation(component,_elementRef, 'modal').then((componentRef)=>{
       this.componentRef = componentRef;
    });
```

What is the equivalent this in past angular-16 version?

Answer (score 1):

`@ViewChild()` should have the `read` parameter set:

```ts
@ViewChild('selector-modal', {read: ViewContainerRef}) child:ModalComponent;
```

And load nextToLocation should look like:

```ts
this._dcl.loadNextToLocation(component, this.child).then((cmpRef) => {
  this.cmpRef = cmpRef;
});
```

See also [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)

Comment: this seems to be proper answer, however, in my case this.child is undefined. Any idea why this may happen?

Comment: You might not have the `#selector-modal`template variable in your template.